# Is there a way to calculate the geometric mean of a raster in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, focal-statistics

For the parameters whose values are log-normally distributed, we should calculate the geometric mean rather than arithmetic mean. In the Focal Statistics, there is option to calculate the arithmetic mean but I am interested to calculate the the geometric mean of my raster file. Is there any way to calculate the geometric mean of a raster in ArcGIS?

I want to calculate geometric mean of the surrounding neighborhood. The same way focal statistics calculate the arithmetic mean with defined map unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099751/737471), just calculate the log, then the arithmetic mean, then the exponent.  You can do this in the raster calculator with something like:

```
Exp(FocalStatistics(Ln(your_raster), your_neighbourhood, "MEAN"))
```

Comment: How do you define neighborhood?

Comment: @FelixIP However you want. Circle, rectangle, annulus, kernel file, directional. It's all in the help for focal statistics. I saw no need to explain as the question wasn't about focal neighbourhoods.

Comment: First step is correct. Next should be exponent of mean cell value from output raster .Single number, not a raster of unknown neighborhood.

Comment: It is a single number. It's the mean value of the neighbourhood pixels. I take the question to be asking for a focal geometric mean, not a geometric mean of the entire raster, otherwise why would the question reference focal statistics?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use script:

```
import numpy as np
iterable = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray("DEM",nodata_to_value=np.NaN)
nan_array = np.isnan(iterable)
not_nan_array = ~ nan_array
a = iterable[not_nan_array]
A = np.log(a)
b = A.sum()/len(A)
print np.exp(b)
```

credits to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099542/python-easy-way-to-do-geometric-mean-in-python) author.

Comment: The OP has clarified the question and wants a geometric mean of a focal neighbourhood, not a geometric mean of the raster.

Comment: @user2856 I see, you were right. What I still struggle to understand is log-normal distribution near cell. Hope asker knows what he really wants.